# How have labels inside the scaled nodes in visNetwork?

Tags: r, graph

In [visNetwork](http://datastorm-open.github.io/visNetwork/), by default text doesn't go inside nodes, instead it appears below it:

```
require(visNetwork, quietly = TRUE)
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3, label=2014:2016 ,value=1:3)
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))
visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%")
```

[image]

Seems like the only way to solve this issue is to use set `shape` property to `circle`:

```
require(visNetwork, quietly = TRUE)
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3, label=2014:2016 ,value=1:3,shape='circle')
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))
visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%")
```

[image]

The problem is that, as you can see in the figure above, now with labels inside circle scaling nodes using `value` property don't work.

So the question is how to have both options ("scale" and "text inside") at the same time?

PS: What a pity, there is no visNetwork tag!

Comment: Would you suggest additional tags?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a tricky way to solve this bug. setting up `font.size` instead of `value` property works fine. You need to scale it for best visualization. For instance I scale it 10 times bigger:

```
require(visNetwork, quietly = TRUE)
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3, label=2014:2016 ,font.size =(1:3)*10,shape='circle')
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))
visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%")
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't there any other solution yet?

Answer (score 3):

I've found another way, adding spaces on bot sides of the label.
That will keep all fonts the same size.

```
n <- 5L
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:3, label=paste0(strrep(" ",n), 2014:2016,
strrep(" ",n)) ,value=1:3,shape='circle')
edges <- data.frame(from = c(1,2), to = c(1,3))
visNetwork(nodes, edges, width = "100%")
```

[image]

If the length of the labels is not the same you may want to try other criteria.