# how to make label size proportional to node size in visNetwork in r

Tags: r, igraph, visnetwork

I'm trying to make a network graph using visNetwork package in r. I have problem trying to make my node label proportional to the node size. I know the node size is controlled by column `size` in `nodes`. But what about the label size?

One additional question. What does `idToLabel` do? I tried to make it TRUE or FALSE, the network graph make no difference.

Thanks a lot.

Here is the sample code.

```
library(visNetwork)
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:10, 
                    label = paste("Node", 1:10),                                 # labels
                    group = c("GrA", "GrB"),                                     # groups 
                    value = 1:10,                                                # size 

                    title = paste0("<p><b>", 1:10,"</b><br>Node !</p>"),         # tooltip
                    color = c("darkred", "grey", "orange", "darkblue", "purple"),# color
                    shadow = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE))                  # shadow

edges <- data.frame(from = sample(1:10,8), to = sample(1:10, 8),
                    label = paste("Edge", 1:8),                                 # labels
                    length = c(100,500),                                        # length
                    arrows = c("to", "from", "middle", "middle;to"),            # arrows
                    dashes = c(TRUE, FALSE),                                    # dashes
                    title = paste("Edge", 1:8),                                 # tooltip
                    smooth = c(FALSE, TRUE),                                    # smooth
                    shadow = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))                       # shadow

visNetwork(nodes, edges, physics=T, idToLabel=T)
```

Answer (score 4):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39674927/how-have-labels-inside-the-scaled-nodes-in-visnetwork) you can control the label size by setting the `font.size`, e.g.:

```
nodes <- nodes %>% mutate(font.size = (1:10)*3)
```

As to your second question: `idtolabel` is defining whether to use vertex IDs as labels or the specified node-labels (see [here](https://github.com/datastorm-open/visNetwork/issues/207)).

Answer (score -2):

You can do this way:

```
visNetwork(nodes, edges, physics=T, idToLabel=T)%>%
  visNodes(size = 10)
```

Comment: Didn't work for me